# Cannot retrieve data from database - Error 1241

Tags: php, mysql

Error

SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT status.id AS id, status.status
FROM STATUS
WHERE id
IN (

SELECT student.id, student.fname
FROM student,
STATUS WHERE student.id =14
)
ORDER BY status_id DESC
```

MySQL said: Documentation
`#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: isn't the error message crystal clear? `WHERE id IN ( SELECT student.id, student.fname .... )`

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` inside the `IN()` should not select more than one column.

Comment: @MalithaDalugoda: Feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer by clicking on the  checkmark and/or up and down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

in the subuery "SELECT student.id, student.fname" you have to extract only one field